# What are the best practices for cross-browser web sites?

Tags: cross-browser

(I'd like this to be the definitive community wiki. I seeded it from my own answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045830/dealing-with-firefox-and-internet-explorers-differences).)

## Specify Everything

A lot of cross-browser issues amount to this: you didn't specify something, and different browsers make different assumptions. Therefore:

### Declare a valid doctype

Your doctype tells the browser what rules you'll be using in your code. If you don't specify, the browser has to guess, and different browsers will guess differently.

In my experience, a "strict" doctype makes IE behave better (enables things like CSS :hover selectors on divs in IE7).

[This article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/) gives good background on doctypes.

### Use Web standards

Avoid browser-specific markup, or only use it when its failure in other browsers won't be significant to the site experience.

### Validate your HTML and CSS

You don't have to get everything perfect, but validation is good feedback. As [Jeff said](https://blog.codinghorror.com/html-validation-does-it-matter/):

> Knowing the rules and boundaries helps you define what you're doing, and gives you legitimate ammunition for agreeing or disagreeing. You can make an informed choice, instead of a random "I just do this and it works" one.

Imagine you opened a paragraph tag and never closed it. If you then open a list tag, did you mean it to be inside the paragraph or not? Validating will help you catch that, close the tag, and eliminate ambiguity.

### Consider a CSS Reset

Different browsers assume different baseline CSS rules. You can help them all to act the same by explicitly ironing out the differences up front. Eric Meyer, who wrote [CSS: The Definitive Guide](http://meyerweb.com/eric/books/css-tdg/), uses [this reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/). Another popular choice is [YUI Reset CSS](http://69.147.76.210/yui/reset/).

## Use a Javascript library for DOM interactions

Whenever your Javascript needs to work with elements on your page, it's best to use a library like jQuery, Prototype, or MooTools. These libraries are used by many thousands of developers, and they take most of the inconsistencies between browsers' interpretation of Javascript, deal with those internally, and give you a consistent set of commands that just work. Trying to find and work around all these inconsistencies yourself is a waste of time and likely to create bugs.

## Test in multiple browsers, deal with IE last

Test in multiple browsers as you go. Generally, you'll find that non-IE browsers behave similarly and IE is a special case - especially if you follow the advice above. When necessary, you can add IE hacks in a separate stylesheet and only load it for IE users.

[Quirksmode.com](http://www.quirksmode.org/) is a good place for hunting down random browser differences.

[Browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/) can help show how your page will be displayed in an assortment of browsers and operating systems.

## Fail Gracefully

No site will look perfect in every browser that exists. If a user doesn't have Flash, or Javascript, or advanced CSS, etc, you want your site to be usable anyway. Design with that in mind:

### Check the bare HTML

Try loading your site with bare HTML - no styles, no scripts. Are menu options available? Does primary content precede secondary content? Is the site usable, even if ugly?

### Consider test-driven progressive enhancement

Described in [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/testdriven/), this technique uses javascript to check if a browser has a given capability, such as support for a given CSS property, before using it on the page. It is unlike browser sniffing because it tests for features rather than a specific browser.

Answer (score 13):

Use a library like jQuery abstract away the differences in the DOM, AJAX and JavaScript.

Comment: Not only to do AJAX. I'd say use one even if you won't do asynchronous calls to the server.

Comment: And to use jQuery specifically, over a "library like jQuery", because of its concerted effort at cross-browser compat.

Comment: @Vinko - Your are correct. I have edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you're keeping HTML, CSS and Javascript in separate files as much a possible. Mixing structure, presentation and behavior in your HTML file just makes finding and fixing problems harder.

Answer (score 2):

Use Firebug in Firefox for:

- Debugging/stepping through your JS.
- Seeing how your stylesheets are being interpreted and hacking them up on the fly to see how to fix your problem.
- See how many calls you are making for remote resources and how long they take.
- Profile your code.

Chrome and IE8 have similar tools built-in that can be used for the same thing.

Opera and Safari (and IE) have [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html).

Comment: Has anybody used the IE8 and Chrome tools mentioned? What are they called and what do you think of them?

Comment: IE8 has an optional "Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar"  Tool [Link Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) that can be installed with it. A more advanced version of this tool comes standard with IE browsers like IE11. You just hit F12 and it will launch.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use CSS Reset on start of your stylesheet...

   You can get one [here](http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/html5-doctor-css-reset-stylesheet/)...
2. Validate your code by w3c ...

   You can validate your code [here](http://validator.w3.org/) by page link or simply copy paste page element

Answer (score 0):

My #1 rule is **use a strict doctype**. HTML or XHTML is fine, but using the strict doctype removes pretty much every browser quirk there is, especially in IE7+.

> Imagine you opened a paragraph tag and never closed it. If you then open a list tag, did you mean it to be inside the paragraph or not?

Actually you can't put any other block tags inside a `<p>` tag, that's why the spec allows you to omit the closing tag. If you start a list without closing a paragraph, then the paragraph is implicitly closed. And the validator won't complain.

That's not to say you *shouldn't* close tags, because it generally makes code easier to skim (you don't need to remember the above rules).

Answer (score -1):

Consider programming you web-site's UI using [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html). With GWT you write all code in Java programming language which GWT then cross-compiles into optimized JavaScript that automatically works across all major browsers.

Comment: How is programming the UI using Google Web Toolkit a Best Practice?

Comment: @Metro Smurf: It specifically addresses the issue of cross-browser JavaScript compatibility, doesn't it?

Comment: Agreed that cross-browser JS compatibility is a best practice. I fail to understand how using Google Web Toolkit is a best practice, though. Likely a difference of opinion.

Comment: "Best Practice is a superior method or innovative practice that contributes to the improved performance". Programming in Java that is compiled into JS is a superior method and GWT is a tool that enables this method.

Comment: What is the advantage of this over a cross-browser Javascript framework?

Answer (score -1):

I think using best practice is the way to go, progressive enhancement is designing with the user in mind and needs to be done with all designers.  I believe that a lot of testing on browsers is a good way to ensure proper content is being displayed, many developers over look this.