# Firefox 3.6 destroyed my page styling!

Tags: css, layout, presentation, firefox3.6

Don't really want to blame mozilla on this one, i'm sure it could be me doing something silly but the page at:

www. neverMindFixed .com

the presentation will work fine on other browsers, just not the latest firefox. anyone clued up on this?

Thanks!

Si

Comment: The people over at http://doctype.com/ are great at these kinds of questions.

Comment: Sceenshots how it does look like and some how it should?

Comment: Is Stack Overflow working together with Doctype? Eg, should I stop posting HTML questions here?

Comment: @littlegreen - doctype is listed at the bottom of this page; they are part of the "league of justice" (loosely partnered with StackOverflow, but not running on same forum software)

Comment: I've been having similar CSS layout problems with my recent upgrade to FF 3.6.

Comment: It may also help to look at this community wiki: "What are the best practices for cross-browser web sites?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064594/what-are-the-best-practices-for-cross-browser-web-sites

Comment: This question is fine for Stack Overflow. HTML/CSS still counts as programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, firstly, your CSS is a mess. Secondly, there's this declaration:

```
#faq-bb li { list-style-image:url(/display_images/stonewall/faq_bullet.gif; list-style-type: none; margin: -2px; padding: 0px;  visible:false;}
```

Note the **very important missing second `)`** around the URL. Looks like FF 3.6 is a bit more picky.

Comment: Another word for picky? Conformant. In reality, it should never have been nice enough to guess where the end of the url( ) was. I kind of wish that they would be more restrictive to prevent bad coding.

Comment: Thanks guys. Firefox seems to be dropping any declarations with unrecognized/erroneous css properties. veeeery harsh compared to other browsers out there.
Tough love i suppose.

Thanks again though, pretty much everyone here was spot on with the "fix your shit css" messages - that is definitely the problem.

Si

Comment: @Si it complains but generally doesn't drop the whole declaration. I tested the fix by just adding in the missing bracket and it worked. It looks like other browsers and FF < 3.6 manage to recover from or safely ignore the missing `)` once they get to the `}` but 3.6 looks for the `)` in the rest of the file and gives up. I agree with the "tough love" approach somewhat, but this just looks like a bug.

Answer (score 4):

You have `visible:false;` -- "false" is not valid value. You either mean `visibility: collapse;`, but that likely has poor support in older browsers, or the old standby `display: none;`.

Please [validate your CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stonewall.org.uk%2Fincludes%2Fdefault.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en).

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of visibility settings... are those all really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stonewall.org.uk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) on the page, which could be causing problems. These ones sound most important:

- document type does not allow element "script" here; assuming missing "head" start-tag
- document type does not allow element "head" here
- document type does not allow element "body" here
- ID "search" already defined
- ...plus a bunch of errors from the Javascript (check your CDATA definitions)

Also as Anonymous pointed out, there are CSS errors. There is no property `visible` - I'm guessing you want `visibility: hidden`. But I'm positive you don't need so many things hidden.

Answer (score 0):

For me also, your website is working on Firefox 3.5 and on Chrome, but Firefox 3.6 has problems. Your presentation is working, but the

```
<span class="hidden"> .... </span>
```

tags are showing up instead of remaining hidden.

Why are those tags there?

If you want to keep them, you probably want to clean up your definition of the "hidden" class, like Anonymous says, you cannot specify "visible: false". Remove it, and then validate the rest of your CSS and HTML. There are really a lot of errors.