# overflowed inline element behave different in FF and chrome

Tags: css

I'm just reading css design pattern of Apache and have an issue about overflowed inline element in a block element.Here is the link

http://www.cssdesignpatterns.com/Chapter%2004%20-%20BOX%20MODELS/Inline%20Box/example.html

You can see that the inline element with class "box" stays in the same line box in chrome but go to the next line in firefox, while the desired behavior is what firefox does.
Can anyone explain for  me why there is the difference in firefox and chrome???

Here is the html:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="default">BEFORE</span>  
  <span class="box">← Left &nbsp; ↑ Top &nbsp; 
                      Bottom ↓ &nbsp; Right → </span>  
  <span class="default">AFTER</span>  
</div>​
```

Here is the css

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.default {
  line-height: normal;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: gold;
}

.box {
  line-height: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding: 20px 120px;
  border-left: 5px solid gray;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  background-color: gold;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 99999px;
  height: 99999px;
  margin-top: 99999px;
  margin-bottom: 99999px;
}

.default {
  line-height: normal;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: gold;
}​
```

Here is the fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/GRwUp/

Comment: ???you can follow the link I posted and inspect element in google chrome and firefox.sorry but I have never used Fiddle before

Comment: so you want each inline element to be in his own line?

Comment: Hi  webdeskil, so sorry for not understanding the rule in stackoverflow. I posted the code above. I just want to be clear why chrome and firefox make it different in this case. I want the span element with arrow be in 2 line like firefox do. Thanks so much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try giving the container a width and padding:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 350px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GRwUp/1/

Comment: Is this what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: yes, that's right. Thanks. But anyway, what I really want is WHAT makes firefox and google chrome bahave differently in this case???Can you help me?According w3c, in the case that inline elements have width that larger than with of containing box, overflow element will go to the next line instead of visible on the first line and overflow the first line

Comment: Well, each browser acts differently on various aspects. That's just the way it is. The only way to deal with those differences is to simply run your website on all major browsers (FireFox, IE, Opera, Chrome and Safari) making sure they all produce the same result and fix the issues otherwise. This is a critical part of the web design - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064594/what-are-the-best-practices-for-cross-browser-web-sites if you find my answer helpful, please accept it.